# Scroll animation - Change image on scroll so it appears to rotate

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm building a website for a client, and they've requested to have the product that they're selling rotate on scroll, similar to what you can see on the apple website:

http://www.apple.com/watch/

I have a folder with every frame of the product rotating. I'm wondering what would the best way be to tackle this. I'm guessing on every scroll, the image has to swap out for the next one? Quite a hard one to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want all your images combined into a single sprite and to use `background-position` to change the "frame".

Below is a somewhat brute force way of achieving this using skrollr. I'm also using a CSS preprocessor which makes the CSS much less verbose than it would be otherwise.

**[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/dxbozwok/)**

Sass/SCSS:

```
$image-width: 240;

.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;

  [class^="sprite-"], [class*=" sprite-"] {
      background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/vpjGWKb.png);
      background-position: 0 0;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      position: absolute;
      width: #{$image-width - 2}px;
      height: 200px;
      display: none;
  }

  @for $i from 0 through 17 {
      .sprite-#{($i + 1)} {
          background-position: unquote(-#{($i * $image-width)}px) 0;
      }
  }
}

.spacer-div {
  margin-bottom: 2000px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="sprite-1" data-0p="display:block" data-5p="display:none"></div>
  <div class="sprite-2" data-0p="display:none" data-5p="display:block" data-10p="display:none"></div>
  <div class="sprite-3" data-0p="display:none" data-10p="display:block" data-15p="display:none"></div>
  <div class="sprite-4" data-0p="display:none" data-15p="display:block" data-20p="display:none"></div>
  <div class="sprite-5" data-0p="display:none" data-20p="display:block" data-25p="display:none"></div>
  <div class="sprite-6" data-0p="display:none" data-25p="display:block" data-30p="display:none"></div>
  <div class="sprite-7" data-0p="display:none" data-30p="display:block" data-35p="display:none"></div>
  <div class="sprite-8" data-0p="display:none" data-35p="display:block" data-40p="display:none"></div>
  <div class="sprite-9" data-0p="display:none" data-40p="display:block" data-45p="display:none"></div>
  <div class="sprite-10" data-0p="display:none" data-45p="display:block" data-50p="display:none"></div>
  <div class="sprite-11" data-0p="display:none" data-50p="display:block" data-55p="display:none"></div>
  <div class="sprite-12" data-0p="display:none" data-55p="display:block" data-60p="display:none"></div>
  <div class="sprite-13" data-0p="display:none" data-60p="display:block" data-65p="display:none"></div>
  <div class="sprite-14" data-0p="display:none" data-65p="display:block" data-70p="display:none"></div>
  <div class="sprite-15" data-0p="display:none" data-70p="display:block" data-75p="display:none"></div>
  <div class="sprite-16" data-0p="display:none" data-75p="display:block" data-80p="display:none"></div>
  <div class="sprite-17" data-0p="display:none" data-80p="display:block" data-85p="display:none"></div>
  <div class="sprite-18" data-0p="display:none" data-85p="display:block" data-90p="display:none"></div>
  <div class="sprite-1" data-0p="display:none" data-90p="display:block" data-95p="display:block"></div>
</div>

<div class="spacer-div">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks, yep thats what I was thinking. Just found this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/coma/sBTzG/13/

Comment: Cool. That's a lot simpler than my method.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple images on your page, each depicting a frame in the animation. You may reduce the number of frames as per your requirements. Then, you can use plugins like [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr), [scrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/), [scrollmagic](http://scrollmagic.io/) and set timing to fade in/out the frames in a sequence.

Comment: or if you have a video animation for those frames, you can also use this plugin https://github.com/develodesign/play-on-scroll